# Replace commas with a tabbed space in many files

Tags: bash, vim, vi, edit

I'm trying to find a way to replace commas `,` with a tabbed space `\t` or, in fact, it can be a single space as well. I would like to do this using BASH, and I was wondering perhaps Vim can accomplish such tasks?

I know I can do this manually or through command line for **one** file with:

```
vi [file] -c :%s/\,/\t/g
```

Would it be possible to do this on a loop of files, such as:

```
for i in *; do [vi command here]; done
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The problem with the vi command is that it enters the file after running it. So I don't think that's the appropriate command to use in the loop

Comment: If you guys can think of an easier way btw, please let me know!

Comment: have you tried sed? sed "s/\,/\\t/g" your_file >> modif_your_file

Comment: If you do ever really really need to use vim, you can always pass it the command to quit as well, but as you've seen, it's overkill for something this simple.

Comment: I think in order to pass vim more than one command, you need to use `ex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) is probably a better bet than `vi` for this task:

```
for i in *
do
   cat $i | tr ',' '\t' > $i.tmp
   mv $i.tmp $i
done
```

Answer (score 5):

not exactly vi, but I think more appropriate

```
for f in * ; do sed -i -e 's/,/\t/g' $f ; done
```

Will for with vi as well (as in your sample). But the shorter way is

```
sed -i -e 's/,/\t/g' *
```

Comment: This did not work, I got an error back saying `sed: 1: "corrlength_N_10.csv": command c expects \ followed by text`

Comment: command c? Are you sure you copied it as is? I'll edit to add the -e option, maybe that will be of help.

Comment: Yes the `-e` fixed the errors, though now it removed the commas and replaced them with a `t`, not a `\t`, so weird. grr

Comment: I appreciate the effort though. I googled sed and it looks like a very useful tool to learn. I'll definitely look into it. For now I used the `tr` solution, worked very beautifully. Your solution also created a copy of all of the comma-separated-files with a `-e` extension. for example, suppose I had file `filename.cvs`, after running your command I had a another set of files with `filename.csv-e`. So weird.

Comment: Hmm.. You definitely didn't exactly did what I wrote... There's no reason it should create `-e`-files...

Comment: Perhaps I screwed something up somewhere. Though I could've sworn I did exactly what you wrote (twice). +1 regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, vim can do exactly that quite well. One trick is to start it as `ex` instead of `vim`. It's the same program, `ex` is just a link to `vim`, but when started as `ex` it comes up in the CLI instead of the screen mode.

```
so ross$ for i in /tmp/f?; do
> ex $i << \eof
> g-,-s// /g
> x
> eof
> done
```

Comment: I really need to look into using `ex` for `vim`. When I googled `running multiple commands from command line with vim`, `ex` came up. Thanks for sticking with the vim answer, +1